# The weirdest bug (or something) in std::vector (or somewhere else). What's going on?

Tags: c++, vector, bug-tracking, stdvector

I've tried compiling this with Visual Studio 2012 RC and Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.1. I'd appreciate if you tried with some other compiler. See my comments in the code to really appreciate the weirdness of this bug. Does anyone know what's going on, and where should I file a bug report about this?

```
// File: NamedSameA.h

#pragma once
```

---

```
// File: NamedSameA.cpp

#include <vector>

#include "NamedSameA.h"

struct NamedSame // Rename this class to something else to make the program work
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    // Comment out the previous line or change
    // the data type to int to make the program work
};

static NamedSame g_data; // Comment out this line to make the program work
```

---

```
// File: NamedSameB.h

#pragma once

void test();
```

---

```
// File: NamedSameB.cpp

#include <vector>

#include "NamedSameA.h"
#include "NamedSameB.h"

struct NamedSame
{
    int              data1; // Comment out this line to make the program work
    std::vector<int> data2;
};

void test()
{
    NamedSame namedSame;
    namedSame.data2.assign(100, 42);
    // The previous line produces the following runtime error:
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // Debug Assertion Failed!
    // Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
    // File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector
    // Line: 240
    // Expression: vector iterators incompatible
}
```

Comment: Erm, [`assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) takes iterators, not integers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - there's a version with `size_t` and `T`, where, in this case, `T` is `int`.

Comment: Is it a violation of One Definition Rule?

Comment: @KirilKirov Oh, I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By giving the same name to two different classes/structures you've violated the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule). This results in undefined behavior, so any result is possible - including a crash.

I've found over the years that the more convinced I am that I've found a compiler bug, the more likely it is that my program has a fundamental flaw.

Comment: But those NamedSame structs are in different cpp-files. They are in different translation units and they have internal linkage. Thus they don't fall under the one definition rule. They should each be a different thing. Also, shouldn't one definition rule violations result in compile time error, and not some weird random, runtime assertions, which only happen in debug mode?

Comment: @zeroes00, I don't see anything in your code sample that would result in internal linkage. The compiler is not required to detect ODR violations and usually it can't because the problem spans translation units. And weird random runtime assertions is actually a good outcome for undefined behavior, it could easily have been worse.

Comment: Okay, my confusion stems from the misconception that the term linkage would apply to classes as well. So I thought classes defined in source (cpp, c, ...) files would somehow be internal to that translation unit and thus completely separate from other translation units. Sometimes I hate C++